# OLAP Hierarchy Creation

Tags: olap, cube-dimension

I have a dimension name is 'Material' that have attributes:

```
Material Type
Letter1
Letter2
Material Name
Material ObjectId
```

I want to create an hierarchy like

```
Material Type
  Letter 1
     Letter 2
        Material
```

Example like : `Inventory of Material -> M ->MI -> MIRROR`
I set the Material Type Key Value: Material Type, and Name Value: Material Name.
But when I browse the dimension I do not see material type names on the first level. I see different material names for different times.

Secondly when I browse my cubes that use the material dimension, I do not see my material hierarchy. Only First level (Material Type) have seen on the secreen.

What I do for these problems. I searched but not found anything...

Answer (score 3):

Well, for define hierarchies, do this questions:

If I group Letter1, I will have a Material Type?

Think of the basic hierarchy: nation, city, neighborhood.

If I join several cities, I have a nation. Once, a city belongs only to one nation.
This example serves to your hierarchy? think about it.

See this link: [OLAP Dimension Structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8490657/olap-dimension-structure/8512670#8512670)